# How to efficiently remove single letter words in Python

Tags: python

I want to remove single letter words such as `a`, `i e`, `e g`, `b f f`, `y o l o`, `c y l` using a Python function.

My current code looks follows.

```
def remove_single_letters(concept):
    mystring = "valid"

    if len(concept) == 1:
        mystring = "invalid"

    if len(concept)>1:
        validation = []
        splits = concept.split()
        for item in splits:
            if len(item) > 1:
                validation.append("valid")
        if len(validation) != 1:
            mystring = "invalid"
    return mystring

print(remove_single_letters("b f f"))
```

It works fine. However, I am wondering if there is a more efficient way (with lesser time) of doing it in python.

Comment: If your program works fine you can also post it on [codereview.se].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a single line solution:

```
def remove_single_letters(concept):
    return ["valid", "invalid"][concept.count(" ") >= len(concept) // 2]
```

Update: Note that this is shorter and cool looking but does not necessarily run faster.

Explanation:

- `concept.count(" ")`: Returns the number of spaces in string
- `>= len(concept) // 2`: Returns True if more than half of the string is spaces (it fails when there are multiple spaces between legitimate words as @user202729 mentioned)
- `["valid", "invalid"][result]`: This part is just for fun: It returns the first element if the `result` is `False` and the second element if the `result` is `True` (because `False` is equal to `0` and `True` is equal to `1`).

Comment: @Selcuk Hii,Can you please explain that line of code

Comment: Indexing a 2-element list with a bool looks cool, but for real code just use a conditional statement instead...

Comment: Using `("valid", "invalid")` is arguably better, but I guess it's fine to have it as a list.

Comment: Also, this fails if there are multiple consecutive spaces.

Comment: @user202729 Which is why I said it's arguably better. If the bytecode and the source say different things, it's not exactly desirable.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for a more concise solution (yet not faster as both solutions are of O(n)) if you want to check if any 1 letter character exists in the string:

```
remove_single_letters = lambda concept:"invalid" if 1 in [len(item) for item in concept.split()] else "valid"
print(remove_single_letters("a b c"))
#prints invalid
```

An ordinary function would be like this:

```
def remove_single_letters(concept):
    return "invalid" if 1 in [len(item) for item in concept.split()] else "valid"
```

They both check the length of elements in the split input to find any item with length of `1` and is insensitive to multiple spaces thanks to `split()`.

If you want to check the strings that are totally made up of single characters:

```
def remove_single_letters(concept):
    u = set(len(item) for item in concept.split()) 
    return "invalid" if len(u) == 1 and 1 in u else "valid"
```

Comment: I guess the requirement is that there should be no consecutive letters. This solution will mark `h ello` as invalid.

Comment: Thanks @Selcuk. I included the solution that reproduces the question's original behaviour. I had misinterpreted the question and proposed a way to check if the any single letter existed in the string.